# Finding out how many objects were reclaimed by the C# garbage collector

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I am interested to find out how many objects were reclaimed by the garbage collector after I run the following code.

```
if (ObjectsOutstanding > GCThreshold) {
    System.GC.Collect();
}
```

Comment: It is rarely advisable to call GC.Collect

Comment: maybe you can override the finalize method and put a counter to register every call to this method but I am not sure if you can do that.

Comment: All sorts of objects or are you auditing your own objects?

Comment: @Henk Holterman: I am auditing my own objects

Comment: Best answer: do not do this. You cannot improve on GC this way, you can hinder it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way of doing this for your own custom-types would be to increment and track some counter in their finalizers.

e.g.

```
public class MyCustomType
{
    public static int NumFinalizersCalled;

    ~MyCustomType()
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref NumFinalizersCalled);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Henk Holterman: `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers` would fix that, wouldn't it?

Comment: I'd throw an `#if DEBUG` precompiler directive in there so that it does not make it into a release build.

Answer (score 0):

In the Visual Studio debugger you can use the [SOS library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx) in the immediate window. There are several GC methods that give you the information you need. I don't know if this is what you want, but it is a starting point.